# would appreciate someone showing me how to work this out

Tags: c++, loops

I am making a little game where you have a pistol and you press 0 to shoot, and each time you do the health decreases by 12 until death then new target, but I can't figure out how to make the loop.

I created stop at 88 (it's at 89 for some reason but I can figure it out sooner or later)
and then count down more when I press the 0 key again. I have tried `if` statements and everything I've really learned so far,
but I cannot figure it out.

```
void gun_shots(int pistol)
{
     std::cout << "100 health ";
     int i = 100;
     while ( i > 87)
     {
         std::cout << i << " ";
         i--;
         if (i == 87)
         {
             std::cout << "AGH i lost health ";
         }
     }
}

 int main()
 {
     std::cout << "0: play game " << std::endl << "1: end game ";
     int shoot;
     std::cin >> shoot;
     switch (shoot)
     {
     case 0:
         gun_shots(shoot);

         break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your loop only continues if `i > 88`. Since 88 is not greater than 88, it will not continue the loop and output 88 but instead exit the loop. It's not clear what you want to do exactly. What is the function `gun_shots` supposed to do exactly?

Comment: oh yes, i knew i was forgetting something, changed it to 87. but gun_shots is my function for the gun, is to shoot, its all imaginary because theres no visuals . but i want it to where i can press a singular key, in my case 0, and it deplete the health as in "100 health" until it reaches 0 health

Comment: Instead of hard-coding `87` into your while-loop condition, why not pass in the value you want `gun_shots()` to decrement to as a second argument, e.g. `void gun_shots(int pistol, int decrementTo) {[...] while (i > decrementTo) {...}`  Then your `main()` function can call it with the appropriate decrementTo value to get the behavior you want.

Comment: Yeah excuse it if it is a mess, i should change that but ive been going along with the tutorials and im trying to branch off and make my own things and im forgetting some things.

Comment: You need to tell us what the problem is. "I cannot figure it out" doesn't tell us.

Comment: i was trying to explain it to the best of my ability, basically i want the 100 i have "100 health" to be subtracted by 12 each time i press the 0 key, and i know how to make it count from 100 to 88, but im having a difficult time figuring out how i can make it subtract by 12 each time i press 0. If anyone knows how to do that, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with: `case 0: health -= 12; break;`

Answer (score 1):

You want to shoot the pistol on each press of the <kbd>0</kbd> key, and you want each shot to decrement the health.  So get rid of the loop in `gun_shots()`, it really doesn't belong there.  Move the loop into `main()` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int health;

void shoot_gun()
{
    health -= 12;
}

bool is_dead()
{
    return health <= 0;
}

void spawn()
{
    health = 100;
    std::cout << "New target spawned" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    spawn();

    do
    {
        std::cout << "health: " << health << std::endl
                  << "0: shoot " << std::endl
                  << "1: end game" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 0:
                shoot_gun();
                if (is_dead())
                {
                    std::cout << "Target died" << std::endl;
                    spawn();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help, i'm not all that experienced im just 14, but this helps a lot.